# node.js multiple continuous volume tcp/sockets - concurrent execution?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp

we have our socket application written in c# and we researching at converting to node.js framework.

I understand node.js is single threaded and execution goes by event loop.

We have multiple send and receive sockets (about 10 send and 10 receive) to different IP's. Basically these are environment, wind, climate and related data that streams continuously round the clock. In other words, a receive socket will never be idle, it always has data to receive continuously and similarly send has something to send continuously.

With that said, will node.js block/backlog or slowdown other 19 sockets when 1 gets into the event loop?

If it does, do I have to run 20 seperate node.exe instances or is there a way to fork it out?

Appreciate your advice's.

Comment: Just reading data from multiple sockets is unlikely to bog the server down.  It matters more what you do with all that continuous data.  Do you write it to a database, to a file?  Just keep it in memory?

Comment: @jfriend00 We send the data to rabbitmq server (on a different machine) and send socket receives data from rabbit and forwards along.

Comment: If a single C# process can handle what you have now, then a single nodejs instance can likely handle it too.  The non-blocking architecture makes it more efficient at handling lots of asynchronous operations (which is what socket reads/writes are in nodejs) than a blocking server architecture.  You will have to code things correctly with non-blocking async operations to realize the nodejs advantage.